# Is it possible to use a MultiOutputRegressor with different hyperparameters for each output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need a `scikit-learn` composite estimator for vector targets, but I need to define different hyperparameters for each target.

My first instinct was to define a `MultiOutputRegressor` of dummy estimators, then overwrite the `estimators_` attribute with the desired regressors, but this does not work as only the base estimator is defined on construction; it is then copied on fit.

Do I need to write my own meta-estimator class, or is there a better solution I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [answered off-site](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/21766) by Dr. Lemaitre - no prepacked solution exists to define multiple different regressors into a single multi-output regressor, but a decent work-around is to use one of the -CV family of regressors such as [ElasticNetCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html) as a base estimator. This will allow different hyperparameters for each output, assuming the parameters can be decently tuned on each instance of `fit`.